# Giving related questions while posting an answer

Tags: feature-request, answers, related-questions

It might be a nice idea if we were able to load related questions while answering a question.

When we ask a question, a list of related questions, based on the title, gets loaded to avoid repetition of the same questions. Likewise, what if we load a related list of questions while answering, which may help finding duplicates, and repetition of answers can be avoided?

Before posting this question I read all the related questions.

Answer (score 4):

There's a "Related" section in the right side of the screen of each question that will show you the related questions that you, as a reader of the question, can look at (possibly to find duplicates).

Comment: Point, I guess I missed that area :). But I feel loading right below answering area may be helpful.